# How do I go from logistic regression to ROC curve and analysis?

Tags: r, probability, logistic-regression, roc, auc

I have a dataset that looks like this, where "1" represents if a host is infected and "0" represents if a host is uninfected at that specified dose. However, the ROC function needs observed data, false positive and true positives to generate the ROC curve. I think that that I am missing a step or miscalculated something but I'm not sure what it is.

```
library(pROC)
dataname <- data.frame(Dose = c(rep(0.2, 8), rep(0.3, 7), rep(0.7, 10)),
                       Infected = c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 5)))
```

I used GLM to get the probability of each host getting infected at each dose size.

```
#logistic model

logistic <- glm(
  formula = Infected ~ Dose,
  data = dataname,
  family = binomial(link = 'logit')
)
```

I then ordered the probabilities from lowest to highest and ranked them:

```
predicted.data<-data.frame(prob.inf = logistic$fitted.values, Infected = dataname$Infected)
predicted.data<-predicted.data[order(predicted.data$prob.inf, decreasing=FALSE),]
predicted.data$rank<-1:nrow(predicted.data)
```

I then ran the roc function and plotted the curve:

```
roc_data <-roc(dataname$Infected, predicted.data$prob.inf)

plot(roc_data, main="ROC Curve", print.auc=TRUE, xlim=(0:1), ylim=(0:1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to order and rank the predicted probabilites.
Assuming you are using the `roc()` function from the `pROC` package you can simply feed it your response `dataname$Infected` and your fitted values `logistic$fitted.values`.

The following code:

```
library(pROC)
dataname <- data.frame(Dose = c(rep(0.2,8),rep(0.3,7), rep(0.7,10)),
                       Infected = c(rep(0,20),rep(1,5)))

logistic <- glm(
  formula = Infected~Dose,
  data = dataname,
  family = binomial(link = 'logit')
)

predicted.data<-data.frame(prob.inf=logistic$fitted.values,Infected=dataname$Infected)

roc_data <-roc(dataname$Infected,predicted.data$prob.inf)

plot(roc_data, main="ROC Curve", print.auc=TRUE,
     xlab = "Specificity (true negative rate)", ylab = "Sensitivity (true positive rate)")
```

produces:

[image]

Which seems correct to me.

Comment: This looks pretty good but why do you reverse the axis with xlim? This reverses your ROC curve...

Comment: You are right, was an artifact from OP's code. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

For a true understanding of model diagnostics it is IMHO quite enlightening to calculate some metrics by hand (which is not overly complicated). In a logistic regression setting you would start with the confusion matrix and get the relavant metrics from there.

Here's a worked out example:

```r
#### Use Challenger Data as a sample data for GLM
data(Challeng, package = "alr4")
c_mod <- glm(fail > 0 ~ temp, data = Challeng, family = "binomial")

### Do calculations by hand

## 1. Create observed vs prediction data.frame
obs_pred <- data.frame(fail = as.integer(Challeng$fail > 0),
                       pred = predict(c_mod, type = "response"))

## 2. Get all potential cutoff values
cs <- c(0, sort(unique(obs_pred$pred)))

## 3. Calculate all potential confusion matrices (i.e. 2x2 observed vs predicted
cms <- lapply(cs, \(co) table(data.frame(obs  = factor(as.integer(Challeng$fail > 0), 1:0), 
                                         pred = factor(as.integer(obs_pred$pred > co), 1:0))))

## 4. Get True Positive Rate (tpr) and False Positive Rate (fpr)
tpr <- vapply(cms, \(tab) tab[1L, 1L] / sum(tab[1L, ]), numeric(1L))
fpr <- vapply(cms, \(tab) tab[2L, 1L] / sum(tab[2L, ]), numeric(1L))

## 5. Plot fpr vs tpr
plot(fpr, tpr, type = "l")
```

[image: False Positive Rate vs True Positive Rate Line Chart]

Now that this is understood, we can use built-in libraries to do the same. There are quite a couple of them (nice comparison can be found [here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/03/01/some-r-packages-for-roc-curves/)). one option is `library(ROCR)`:

```r
library(ROCR)

## 1. Create 'prediction' object (c.f. ?ROCR::prediction)
pp_c <- with(obs_pred, prediction(pred, fail))

## 3. Get True Positive Rate (tpr) and False Positive Rate (fpr)
perf_c <- performance(pp_c, "tpr", "fpr")

## 4. Plot
plot(perf_c)

## 5. Same as by hand calculation
all.equal(rev(fpr), perf_c@x.values[[1L]])
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(rev(tpr), perf_c@y.values[[1L]])
# [1] TRUE
```

[image: False Positive Rate vs True Positive Rate Line Chart]

From the confusion matrix (and a bit of basic geometry) you can also calculate the area under the curve:

```r
### AUC Calculations
sw <- cbind(fpr = rev(fpr), tpr = rev(tpr))
sum(diff(sw[, "fpr"]) * (sw[-nrow(sw), "tpr"] + diff(sw[, "tpr"]) / 2))
# [1] 0.78125
performance(pp_c, "auc")@y.values[[1L]]
# [1] 0.78125
```

Comment: Thanks for the guide, but I'm still confused as to how I would use my data to get the predicted data in this case. The GLM will give me a list of probabilities. I need the probability of being a "0" or "1" at each dose. So would it be incorrect for me to use the method that was previously commented? Is that method not doing the same thing?

Comment: Well, that is the very idea of a roc curve. You define different cut off points and declare a prediction as 1 when it exceeds your cutoff point. You do that for „all“ cutoff points and for each you calculate fpr and tpr which you plot eventually. Look at my code and how iI define 0/1 for each cutoff.